# Why would you use Oracle database?

Tags: database, oracle, comparison

I'm curious for technical reasons why you choose Oracle database versus the latest flavors of:
1) Microsoft SQL Server
2) MySQL
3) PostgreSQL

What features or functionality justify the extra cost.
I'm interested in technical arguments, not a religious war. 
A friend asked me this and I've always used one of the 3 I listed.
I didn't know enough about Oracle Databases to offer an opinion.

Thanks.

Answer (score 54):

Noone seems to talk about the cost of developers time working with Oracle.  Most developers who know any other db hate Oracle, those that don't assume that all DB code and/or ORM tools are difficult to use.

If I started a business that I believed was going to scale to Amazon proportions I might consider NoSQL solutions, otherwise I'd choose PostgreSQL, SQL Server (or indeed even Sybase now) over Oracle every time.  I say this having worked (as a dev) with Oracle for 2 years - its terrible to work with!

Comment: i disagree! Oracle is definitely one of the best implementations of RDBMS. It manages memory very efficiently and can handle complex JOIN operations which easilly cripple MySQL and MsSQL. Oracle has a great Architecture, it makes it rock solid because it is very easy to organise different applications data very well. I think the best plus for me is the SQL Engine that Oracle possess, it is very advanced, making it the only database to operate a data warehouse! Running complex queries on Oracle is just easy.Other features like Materialized Views, PL/SQL e.t.c. make Oracle have value for money.

Comment: I agree as well - having worked with both Oracle 11gR2 and SQL Server 2008 R2 for the last several years it is absolutely ridiculous how many times I've run up against Oracle's broken security model, unintuitive performance tuning tools, and finicky optimizer.  Whatever savings you get by foregoing an MS Win Server license will immediately be eaten up by lost productivity.

Comment: As a primary user of SQL Server and have developed a database using Oracle: Oracle is a pain in the a*se. Like @Jasmine mentioned, it's so limited to what you can do. I especially hate how variables work and the fact you have to create triggers and sequences for auto incrementing IDs. SQL Server is the definition of how a database should operate. Heck, even MySQL is better than Oracle. Of course both databases has it's limitations, but nothing compared to what Oracle has.

Comment: Furthermore, PLSQL is clunky and annoying.

Comment: Oracle has limited sharding support, limited scaling support, limited administration features, limited support help, somewhat-limited clustering support (no master-master log shipping), and lots of vendor lock-in. They're currently attempting to catch up, but I've never seen so many bugs. I've worked with a number of alpha releases, beta releases, and systems declared unfit & unstable. I've still never seen so many clear bugs that should have been obvious before release or sometimes before even compiling.

Answer (score 35):

Only Oracle and Microsoft's SQLServer are closed source, and when something goes wrong and you have a problem the answer is just a phone call away (and cash if course). Anyways MySQL and PostGre have several enterprise consulting services but in the end these consultants aren't really resposible for the product, because the product belongs to everyone. Which is great because you can go in and fix the code if you are good with C and relatively lowlevel programming, but if you aren't finding the solution might become a wild goose chase.

Now since not everyone is skilled enough, and those enterprises with money prefer the security (in the business sense) of the closed source databases, is the reason why these solutions haven't gone out of business, besides the fact that their implementations are solid and worth the money if you have it.

Ok now finally the most important difference is between SQLServer and Oracle and that difference is the OS, most people using Windows will stick with, you guessed it, SQLServer, but if you run on flavors of Unix Oracle is your closed source solution. Anyways I use Oracle on Solaris, but if our target were Windows I would probably use SQLServer because both products are rock solid, but I trust Microsoft has some special tricks under the hood to get the best performance on windows.

Comment: +1. Good answer. I always worked with the motto "I like best of breed, but free is very cool." I always try to work out a balance when choosing a solution. For my day job I use SQL Server. On my own stuff MySQL right now.

Answer (score 3):

Just to name a few:

- Oracle Real Application Cluster - provides advanced clustering features
- [Oracle Data Guard](http://www.oracle.com/technology/deploy/availability/htdocs/DataGuardOverview.html) - in short provides physical and logical stand-by features.
- Oracle Exadata - implements the database aware storage (that can do predicate filtering, column projection filtering, join processing, hastens tablespace creation). The solution comes with HP servers, full 24/7 warranty, and other nice things. It's quite nice for applications with highly intensive data loading (for example thanks to the independent tablespace creation).
- Oracle Virtualization

And of course the magic of the brand ;)

And when it comes to choosing the RDBMS? Usually the choice is pretty obvious - Oracle or the rest of the world. After that you can narrow the choice down by:

- platform (windows-only or not)
- weight (sqlite, MySQL, PostgreSQL, ...)
- budget (initial license cost, maintenance + support cost)
- evolution perspectives, for example:

  - Oracle Express -> Oracle
  - SQL Server Express -> MSSQL
- business perspectives - "secure, well known product" or open-source product (bear in mind the quotation around the first phrase). Other post tends to look deeper into this aspect.

Comment: It'd be nice if you could add a little bit about what these features do... for those of us not in the know, it just sounds like buzzword bingo. ;)

Comment: Not only that, but a lot of this stuff isn't necessary for small and medium sized businesses, and certainly does not justify (for them) the very large cost.

Comment: You pay for what you use... The examples I gave are interesting for rather big organisations.

And as I said, first choice it's usually to decide whether to go with Oracle or something else.

Comment: Oracle RAC is not advanced clustering (and wasn't in 2009), it's turnkey clustering. Because it requires shared storage, it will not scale IO. It woul not scale to cloud levels in 2009, and in the last decade, things have only gotten worse for Oracle.

Answer (score 3):

The real question is, what kind of application is going to be used to make use of a RDMS. You certainly don't need oracle for your wordpress blog or twitter clone. But if you want to do some heavy business intelligence, then Oracle might have some features which can help doing that more efficiently than the others.

Ms sql server is very good aswell, it has tons of features. If you are struck on linux and you need a database with features as offered by ms sql, then oracle would be a good pick.

Answer (score 3):

I think it's because **Oracle** was the first RDMS that supported "**sharding**"

Comment: -1 What does this even mean?

* Citation needed.
* There are multiple methods to implement sharding, including but not limited to implementing sharding in application layer.

Comment: Oracle didn't have native sharding until 12.2 (2016/2017). IIRC, MySQL beat them by more than a decade (different storage engines).

Answer (score 1):

The costs of SQL Server and Oracle are not that far apart, you know.

In fact for small systems the cost of Oracle vs Your Favourite Free Database is between zero (Oracle Express Edition) and not-very-big ($5,800 processor perpetual for Standard Edition One).

Here's a link to the capabilities of the various editions in 11g: http://www.oracle.com/database/product_editions.html.

List prices are available for all territories at http://store.oracle.com -- typically large companies do not pay retail, of course ;)

Comment: the costs of Postgres / MySQL and Oracle are though... (not that I stand by either of those especially)

Comment: +1 David, can you expand your answer to maybe include some of the limitations of the Express Edition?

Comment: @ annakata -- XE is free. SE1 is very cheap.

Comment: Primary limitations af Express (XE) are 4 GB of data, 1 GB of RAM, 1 CPU.

Comment: More recent versions of OracleXE (11.2) have an 11 gb size limit.

Comment: This doesn't account for the much higher cost of maintaining an Oracle DB installation as opposed to MSSQL or its other competitors.

Comment: @MontyWild I would take into consideration the impact of cloud hosting on that. Maintenance costs, in terms of staffing and expertise for managing backup and recovery, for example, can be dramatically less now than when the question was originally asked.